# VPS Node and top -c

Tags: linux, openvz, top

When using and viewing top -c with openvz does the CPU usage and everything include usage for everyone else on the system or just you?

I've been watching my VPS node for awhile now and I've seen spikes into 10.00 and all I have running are simple websites and no major traffic spikes at all. Just everyday usage. So just wondering if its global including all containers? As I remember OpenVZ is different from XEN as it is not a dedicated container like XEN.

Comment: I didn't realize that OpenVZ was used in cases where you don't trust you neighbour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the OpenVZ host you can check the cpu usage of each container.

```
 vzcalc -v <VPSID>
```

But if you cannot administer the OpenVZ box you are correct that:

"often tools like top that show you cpu and memory usage display information for the entire system instead of your individual VPS"

Source: -> http://forums.vpslink.com/linux/465-openvz-cpu-mem-monitor.html

Comment: Thanks. What I was looking for. Needed to know that it was global or individual container.